# Does Umbraco offer inbuilt feature or interface to create categories, menus, or product gallery?

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, development-environment

Does Umbraco offer inbuilt feature or interface to create categories, menus, or product gallery?

I have been searching an easiest way to do so for my clients.

Hope, I can find an smart answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umbraco comes with a limited number of starterkits, skins and macro templates. You can use any of these as you like, but as they are fairly simple, generally you will end up building what you want. One of the great advantages of Umbraco is this kind of flexibility. Umbraco is geared towards developers who have a .Net background, and is very easy if you have .Net experience.  If not, there's a little bit of a learning curve, but there are a good number of resources available as well as an active community to aid in the learning process.

Umbraco has about 4 or so built in starterkits and Our Umbraco has [several more](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/starter-kits) that other users have contributed.

Answer (score 1):

Another place to try would be to look at how some of the e-commerce starter kits work like the uWebShop or TeaCommerce packages.  They have a category/products structure in content that you could take a look at.